# Cronjob script trouble launching application

Tags: cron, raspbian

I started with cronjobs a while ago, but up until yesterday I've run into a problem I can't figure/find out.

```
@reboot me /etc/application/start-script.sh
```

I have Raspbian Jessie (minimal) installed on a Raspberry Pi Zero. One of the users has a cronjob command @reboot. When I check "sudo /etc/init.d/cron status", I can see the cronjob is picked up after a reboot and executed. The only thing is that any output is dropped, the "No MTA installed"-message, (care?).

```
#!/bin/bash
# My start script

logfile=/home/me/logfile.log

echo "Starting program..." >> $logfile
application
echo "Program started!" >> $logfile
```

As you can see, it should create a log file, and it does this after a reboot when the script is called as a cronjob. This script works perfectly fine when you manualy execute it, it writes the output to the logfile AND starts the program.

The problem is: the program is not launched when the .sh script is called as a cronjob.

Why is only the application not started when the script is executed???

**"sudo /etc/init.d/cron status" output**

```
Mar 17 22:14:45 pizza-pi systemd[1]: Starting Regular background program processing daemon...
Mar 17 22:14:45 pizza-pi systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Mar 17 22:14:45 pizza-pi cron[292]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Mar 17 22:14:45 pizza-pi cron[292]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Mar 17 22:14:45 pizza-pi CRON[296]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user me by (uid=0)
Mar 17 22:14:45 pizza-pi CRON[318]: (me) CMD (etc/application/start-script.sh)
Mar 17 22:14:45 pizza-pi CRON[296]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Mar 17 22:14:45 pizza-pi pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user me
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the /etc/rc.local file and add the following line in /etc/init.d/cron/start  be sure that it should before exit 0.

Follow this link https://rahulmahale.wordpress.com/2014/09/03/solved-running-cron-job-at-reboot-on-raspberry-pi-in-debianwheezy-and-raspbian/

Hope answer is useful for you

Comment: I've tried adding "/etc/init.d/cron/start" and "/etc/init.d/cron start" to the /etc/rc.local file, but without succes.

Like I said, the script is executed @reboot, the lines to write out to the log file is succesfull after every reboot. Just the line that starts the application does not work when the script is run as a cronjob.